# tags being re-ordered?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555377/how-to-offscreen-render-a-specific-field-in-vtk). And I put three tags one after one, vtk, c++ and python. To my surprise, the python tag always goes to the first. So the displayed title in my Chrome's tab is `python - How to.....`. (I hope it to be `vtk - How to.....`)

Is this a deliberate design?

Comment: Obligatory duplicate from the über-meta: [Are the tags shown in a particular order?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87508/164403)